# How can I hg pull --rebase without touching my local feature branch?

Tags: git, version-control, mercurial

I am working on a feature and had a few commits on a local feature branch we'll call `/feature`. I then remembered I had some unrelated changes on `default` I needed to push, so I switched over to default and ran an `hg pull -u --rebase` in preparation for an `hg push -b .`

What I expected to happen is that my local changes on the default branch would be rebased onto any changes I pulled in from the remote repository.

What really happened is exactly that, PLUS all of my changes on my feature branch were pulled out and rebased onto the new `default`. As far as I can tell, they weren't even on the feature branch anymore, they just all got moved over to default.

In the end I worked around the issue by exporting and then stripping all my feature commits, then doing the `hg pull -u --rebase` with them gone. I then pushed my changes from default and reimported the feature commits. Ideally I'd like to not have to do this in future.

Is this how git behaves too? I seem to remember otherwise but it's been a while.

Comment: It's not clear to me how `hg pull` should treat *both* `-u` *and* `--rebase` options given together. Both Git and Mercurial do rebase by copying commits to new-and-improved commits (and then dropping the originals by default), but the set of commits that `hg rebase` copies is selected by a very different algorithm. Note that `git pull` means *run git fetch, then run a second Git command*, which is different from `hg pull` which means run just the obtain-commits command. However, the `-u` option means "then run `hg update`", and `--rebase` means "then run `hg rebase`".

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but hg graft might have been an easier way to workaround the problem after the pull.